# messagebox not showing up in windows 10 masm

Tags: assembly, masm, messagebox, masm32

I'm trying to get into asm using masm32 but the simple sample code from the tutorial doesn't work

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data
BUFFER_LENGTH EQU 1024
szMessageBoxFormat BYTE "The resul is %d", 0
szMessageBoxText BYTE 0 dup(BUFFER_LENGTH)

.code

start:

main proc
  push 3
  call display_number_in_message_box
  ret
main endp

display_number_in_message_box proc
  ;Create a string representation of the number
  mov eax, [esp + 4]
  invoke wsprintf, ADDR szMessageBoxText, szMessageBoxFormat, eax

  ;Display that string in a message box
  invoke MessageBoxA, NULL, ADDR szMessageBoxText, NULL, MB_OK

  ret 4
display_number_in_message_box endp

end start
```

I am using `C:\masm32\bin\ml.exe /c /coff /Cp ex0.asm` and `C:\masm32\bin\link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /LIBPATH:C:\masm32\lib ex0.obj` to create an exe, but when running it nothing happens, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `ADDR` before `szMessageBoxFormat` when you invoke `wsprintf`, so you end up passing an invalid address (probably `20656854h`, i.e. `"The "` interpreted as a `DWORD`).