# Assembly MessageBox program

Tags: windows, assembly

Can anybody be so kind and supply me the simplest `MessageBox` assembly program for `Windows` in both `MASM` and `NASM` flavor? I'd like to compare both versions based on this two different compilers.

P.S.
I'm asking the question because I've searched a lot and didn't find clear and simple examples of that kind.

Comment: Here is [one for nasm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66323292/547981)

Comment: And [one for masm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59049154/547981). It's using the `invoke` macro but you could of course `push` the arguments by hand too.

Comment: And [one for €ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#HelloWorld), both for 32bit and 64bit Windows, ANSII or WIDE versions.

Comment: An answer on [How to write hello world in assembly under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032422) uses MessageBoxA from MASM, manually setting up the args, for 32-bit and 64-bit.  Another answer on the same question [does the same with NASM for x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27988874/224132), including showing commands to build+link.